# В Laravel проекте, есть страницы с множеством html тегов как лучше всего сделать перевод?

Tags: laravel

Есть способы  `lang файлы, ru.json файл  и includes` что выбрать, есть ли другие способы в таких случаях может плагин или database ?

текста много вперемешку с html-ом․

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее оптимальная стратегия локализации проекта - это комбинация методов.

Cтатические тексты (интерфейс, разметка) - тут лучше всего использовать `lang` файлы, т.к. этих файлов может быть много с самыми разными контекстами (например `lang/en/auth.php`, `lang/en/validation.php`).

Различные ошибки или внешние файлы (в `vendor`) - удобно использовать `lang/[locale].json` файлы, но здесь важен базовый язык проекта, как правило - это английский. Некоторые ошибки и темплейты из коробки laravel используют `__()` хэлпер, как раз `json` файлы позволяют это локализовать.

А вот динамический контент, который задается в админке сайта (записи, контент страницы и т.п.) - однозначно переводы хранятся в БД. Причем тут в зависимости от проекта можно хранить переводы в `json` полях, где ключи будут локалями, либо в отдельной таблице с `morph` связью

Comment: А можно ли HTML хранить в  lang файлах

Comment: в `lang` файлах можно хранить строки. Если там будет html - это лишь вопрос вставки его в шаблон. Я пока не могу себе представить ситуацию, где надо было бы хранить html в статических файлах переводов. Можно подготовить blade шаблон и в него вставлять локализованные строки